# What is the usage of User Stories Query?

Tags: rally

I'm trying to build a custom application to draw an 8 user stories card per page. this is intended to be used for printing all user stories (and save paper :)).

for some reason i failed and i can't seem to find documentation in Rally SDK regarding the usage?

Especially what are all the options for `types` field in the query?
i saw some examples in SO and in the web of `types: ['HierarchicalRequirement']`.. what is the meaning of this type, and what other options can i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the Print Story Cards app in the app catalog?

http://developer.help.rallydev.com/print-story-cards-app

It prints 4 per page- it shouldn't be difficult to modify that to do 8.

HierarchicalRequirement is the name for a user story.  You can see all the available types and their fields in the WSAPI docs here:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/